# What is a generic word that describes something a person is or does like a skill?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I am in charge of deciding the name of a skill in a role-playing game that serves as a catch-all for abilities/skills that are otherwise unlisted in our handbook (think skills that will help players flesh-out their character's personality, quirks, and life).  Such a skill could be a profession type, a craft (e.g.,whittling), or something more exotic like hyperlexia.

- `Profession` and `Craft` do not capture the spirit well enough.
- `Ability` seems too generic, as are its multi-word variants, e.g. `Unlisted Ability`.
- `Knack` seems closer to the mark but open to suggestions.

Comment: Did you look for a list of synonyms for "Ability"? There is a whole crowd of them, and some one of them ought to fit...

Comment: Would something like *qualities* or *traits* work?

Comment: Perhaps 'talent'.

Comment: Also, perhaps something ending in 'smith' or 'wright'.  'Flairwright' or 'Knacksmith'

Comment: I'm not sure there's a hypernym for this, it seems too fuzzy. Maybe something like "Miscellaneous abilities"?

Comment: What are the abilities/skills that *are* listed in your game already?

Comment: It would help if you described things that aren't included in this category, as well as providing more details on the words you rejected - "do not capture the spirit well enough" is completely useless for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Talent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/talent) per M-W, see the fifth definition in particular for the purposes you describe in a game for how this fits an RPG:

> 1
>
> a
> : a special often athletic, creative, or artistic aptitude
>
> b
> : general intelligence or mental power : ABILITY
>
> 2
> : the natural endowments of a person
>
> 3
> : a person of talent or a group of persons of talent in a field or activity
>
> 4
>
> a
> : any of several ancient units of weight
>
> b
> : a unit of value equal to the value of a talent of gold or silver
>
> 5
> archaic : a characteristic feature, aptitude, or disposition of a person or animal

Answer (score 0):

`Idiosyncrasies` and `Peculiarities` come to mind; these longer words tend to be more intriguing for games. Both usually describe behaviors but can be be attributed to other aspects of characters.

`Secrets` is good, for adding a mysterious or adventurous feel, but may be inappropriate if these traits are public knowledge. `Mystique` and `Intrigue` could work for publicly known traits.

On the boring (read: neutral) side both `Remarks` and `Notes` work as catch-alls.

In context of a game, you can also use some object as a metaphor / allusion to such properties, eg `Undertones` or `Fingerprints` or something from the in-game universe.